# Typescript "Type is not assignable to type" error

Tags: typescript

There are two errors I'm getting when trying to learn TypeScript.

```
Type 'string | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | RegExp | QuerySelector<string | RegExp> | undefined'.

Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | RegExp | QuerySelector<string | RegExp> | undefined'.
```

This line in particular:

```
const warrior = await Warrior.findOne({ warriorname })
```

This comes from the code

```
async (warriorname) => {
    const warrior = await Warrior.findOne({ warriorname })
    return !warrior
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the error it seems that `Warrior.findOne` would happily accept something like this:

```js
const warrior = await Warrior.findOne({ warriorname: 'some string' })
```

or this:

```js
const warrior = await Warrior.findOne({ warriorname: undefined })
```

or *even this*:

```js
const warrior = await Warrior.findOne({ warriorname: /some regex/ })
```

but **not this**:

```js
const warrior = await Warrior.findOne({ warriorname: null })
```

---

Having said that, your `warriorname` variable (again, judging only by the error) looks like it can be either a `string` (which would work) or `undefined` (which would work) or `null` (which would **not** work).

You can fix this by handling the `null` case separately, like so:

```js
if (warriorname === null) {
   return some error;
}

const warrior = await Warrior.findOne({ warriorname })
...
```